# What is the proper way to iterate with rss-atom-bundle?

Tags: symfony, rss

I am trying to figure how to properly use the rss-atom-bundle symfony2 bundle.  A code sample I have below

```
foreach($rssfeedurl as $url){
            $reader = $this->container->get('debril.reader');
            $feed = $reader->getFeedContent($url, $date);
            $items = $feed->getItems();
}
```

The first time through the loop I get what I expect. A list of items from the feed.  The second time through the loop I am not getting anything.

So, my question is what is the proper way to use the rss-atom-bundle so I can iterate through a list of urls and grab each items?

Answer (score 0):

I found some code on github where somebody did this.

The way they did it and it worked for me was to put all the urls into the method parameters as follows:

```
$reader = $this->container->get('debril.reader');
$feed = $reader->getFeedContent($url1,$url2, $date);
$items = $feed->getItems();
```

There is no iteration.